# How to connect between the sessionStorage in PHP to JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to transfer data in my PHP (html) page, befor the HTML is loaded, so I will be able to deal with it after the page is loaded in my JS file.
my php look like this:

```
<?php
/*some php code*/
$dataFromDataBase = "..";
session_start();
$_SESSION['data'] = $dataFromDataBase;

if(isset($_SESSION['data']))
    echo $_SESSION['data'];
else
    echo "<br>False";       
?>
<html>
<!--My Html code..-->
</html>
```

the "if" condition is there now to check if the session was created in the php.
now it echo me the data, so it's meen the session exist.
my JS look like that:

```
if(sessionStorage.getItem("data")){
//do some thing..
}else{
alert("the data isn't set.");
}
```

and the data isn't exist... I've tride to alert the data, and it send me "null"..
they offered me to output into JS directly like that:

```
<script>
var fromserver="<?php
/*some code.. */
echo "**BIG DATA**";
?>";
```

but it is just untidy code.. and the data is pretty big so I can't use coockies

Comment: by the way I'm useing Jquery in the same JS file if it make any change..

Comment: `$_SESSION` is very different from `sessionStorage`, despite the similar name they are not the same.

Comment: `$_SESSION` exists on the server while `sessionStorage` is on the client. They are very separate and cannot communicate directly. To get something from the `$_SESSION` in to your JS code you would be best to make an AJAX request to retrieve it

Comment: Yes, or use PHP to echo out $_SESSION variables on your webpage? You could echo "<script> var user = ". $_SESSION['user'] ." ;</script>

Comment: why not use ajax to pass the vars back and forth?

Comment: also another note - it's bad practice to mix php and js and should be avoided at all costs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating executable JS code from user provided data is a major security issue, so you should avoid the statements like `var someJsVar = '<?= $somePhpVar;?>;'`.  Injecting malicious code could be a simple as `'; malicious-code-here //`

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Attacks

It would be more secure to have your page make an API call on page load, which would return your data for `sessionStorage` encoded as JSON.  This way the browser will see a variable containing the user data, and not the raw data itself.

```
#Initial page
<body>
    <script>
         $.GET("/session-storage.php").success(function(response){
             sessionStorage.setItem("data", response);
         });
    </script>
</body>


#API Call (session-storage.php)
<?php
    $dataFromDataBase = "..";

    echo json_encode($dataFromDataBase);
?>
```

Comment: The problem with that is that it take to much time.. because first the page will be loaded and only then the js will send the call to the php file

Comment: The performance difference will be negligible and the security boost makes it worth it.

Comment: Also, if you're returning `"**BIG DATA**"`, the user is just going to be sitting at a white screen while the page loads.  They'll have a better experience if you load the initial page, then display a spinner or message letting them know their data is being loaded.

Answer (score 7):

`$_SESSION` and `sessionStorage` are completely different.

[sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) saves data like `$_SESSION` except a sessionStorage variable is set on the client's side. [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) is like `sessionStorage` so I see your misunderstanding, however, this sets data on the server-side and does not cross over to `sessionStorage`.

If you really need that `$_SESSION` data in `sessionStorage`, you can echo a script which sets the `sessionStorage` to your `$_SESSION` data. Here's a very simple example below.

```
<?php session_start;

$_SESSION['data'] = "yourdata";

echo '<script> sessionStorage.setItem("data", "' . $_SESSION['data'] . '");</script>';

//Display 'data'.
echo '<script> alert(sessionStorage.getItem("data")); </script>';
```

EDIT: To make it more clearer, notice how `$_SESSION` is done in PHP (server-side) and `sessionStorage` has to be set in JavaScript with the `<script>` tags. Below is a solution to your problem.

```
<?php
/*some php code*/
$dataFromDataBase = "..";
session_start();
$_SESSION['data'] = $dataFromDataBase;

if(isset($_SESSION['data']))
{
   echo '<script> sessionStorage.setItem("data", "' .$_SESSION['data'] .'");</script>';
}
else
{
    echo "<br>False";   
}    
?>
<html>
<!--My Html code..-->
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can take data from php variable and use it in JS.. like this

```
var sessionData = <?php echo $_SESSION['data'];?>
if (typeof sessionData != "undefined" && sessionData == null){
//do some thing..
}else{
alert("the data isn't set.");
}
```